# Javascript validation input type file

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using jquery validate method and I'm using custom javascript to display image name that has been uploaded because of css issue.

Validation message is shown when no input file specified but when user uploads file, message is still displayed. It removes when user clicks somewhere. That's the problem. It should be removed when user adds some image.

How should I fix that?

My code is the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var rules, msgs, inputName;
rules = {};
msgs = {};

var images = ['front_passport', 'back_passport'];
var extn = "jpeg|jpg|png|pdf";
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var inputImage = images[i];
    rules[inputImage] = {};
    rules[inputImage].required = true;
    rules[inputImage].extension = extn;

    msgs[inputImage] = 'Please provide an image with one of the following extensions : jpg, png or pdf';


}

var validateObj = {}
validateObj["rules"] = rules;
validateObj["messages"] = msgs;
validateObj["onkeyup"] = function(element) {
    $(element).valid();
};
validateObj["errorPlacement"] = function(error, element) {
    if ($(element).hasClass('app-file')) {
        error.insertAfter($(element).next().next());
    }

};
validateObj["success"] = function(element) {};
validateObj["submitHandler"] = function(form) {
    form.submit();
}

//files displaying image name



'use strict';

(function(document, window, index) {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.app-file');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
        var label = input.nextElementSibling,
            labelVal = label.innerHTML,
            divName = label.nextElementSibling;

        input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            var fileName = '';
            if (this.files && this.files.length > 1)
                fileName = (this.getAttribute('data-multiple-caption') || '').replace('{count}', this.files.length);
            else
                fileName = e.target.value.split('\\').pop();

            if (fileName) {
                divName.innerHTML = fileName;
            } else {
                label.innerHTML = labelVal;
            }
            $("#individual-form").validate(validateObj);
        });

        // Firefox bug fix
        input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
            input.classList.add('has-focus');
        });
        input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
            input.classList.remove('has-focus');
        });
    });
}(document, window, 0));
$("#individual-form").validate(validateObj);
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="front_passport" class="col-md-2 label-file">Front ID/Passport</label>
   <div class="form-required">*</div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
  {{ Form::file('front_passport',  ["class"=>"app-file"]) }}
  <label for="front_passport" class="file-upload"><span>Upload a File</span></label>
  <div class="file-name"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="back_passport" class="col-md-2 label-file">Back ID/Passport</label>
   <div class="form-required">*</div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
  {{ Form::file('back_passport',  ["class"=>"app-file"]) }}
  <label for="back_passport" class="file-upload"><span>Upload a File</span></label>
  <div class="file-name"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Edited: I found a solution like that:
`$(this).next().next().next().remove();`

but instead of this method how to select next label with class `error` - which is in fact this error message that I want to remove?

Updated: My html markup when submit form and there is no file uploaded is:

```html
<div class="col-md-8">

  <input type="file" name="front_passport" class="app-file error">
  <label class="file-upload" for="front_passport"><span>Upload a File</span></label>
  <div class="file-name"></div><label for="front_passport" generated="true" class="error">Please provide an image with one of the following extensions : jpg, gif, png or pdf</label>
</div>
```

Comment: $(this).find('.error') ?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution - added a new class to div and then remove it:

```js
if( fileName ) {
  divName.innerHTML = fileName;
  $(this).parents('.file-wrapper').find('.error').remove();

}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="front_passport" class="col-md-2 label-file">Front ID/Passport</label>
  <div class="form-required">*</div>
  <div class="col-md-8 file-wrapper">

    {{ Form::file('front_passport',  ["class"=>"app-file"]) }}
    <label for="front_passport" class="file-upload"><span>Upload a File</span></label>
    <div class="file-name"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```